# web3.php - How to call a contract function that mutates states?

Tags: web3.php

I'm creating web3 instance

```
            $web3 = new Web3(
                        new HttpProvider(
                            new HttpRequestManager(
                                config('infura.endpoint'),       // url
                                5.0                              // timeout
                            )
                        )
                    )
            ;
```

Then instance of my contract

```
$contract = new Contract($web3->provider, $abi);
```

I must call this function

```
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "_index",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "_data_to_store",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "name": "set",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
```

I am trying

```
$contract->at(config('infura.contract_address'))
    ->send('set', 22, 'hello world', function($error, $result) {
            // this is Laravel dump to screen and die command
            dd("error", $error, "result", $result);
        }
    )
;
```

The problem is that send throws an Exception. The Exception's message is

> "Wrong type of eth_sendTransaction method argument 0."

Could you please explain me how to use the send method?

EDIT 1:

I tried a different syntax

```
$contract->at(config('infura.contract_address'))
    ->send('set', 22, 'hello world', [ 'from' => config('infura.wallet_address') ], function($error, $result) {
            dd("error", $error, "result", $result);
        }
    )
;
```

But I got a more fun differenct exception

> The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available 
>   at web3.php\src\RequestManagers\HttpRequestManager.php

Answer (score 0):

I found myself the problem.

Infura doesn't support unsigned transactions.

Actually I've not found how to use sendRawTransactions (and to sign). but this is a whole other question